# Compilation errors appear when building a feature patch

Tags: eclipse, patch

I have a plugin which is compiled with JDK 1.5.  If I change the compiler to JDK 1.6, I will get some compilation errors.  So, I set the Java >Compiler preference to JDK 1.5.

Now I need to create a feature patch with that plugin specified in the feature patch.  The feature patch gets created without errors.  But when I export the feature patch project as a deployable feature, I get the same compilation errors above; like the IDE reverted to JDK 1.6.  How do I force the build here to use JDK 1.5?

THANK YOU!

Comment: At a firm I was working with last year, we still had clients (2010 remember) who were just upgrading to Java 1.4 because they didn't want to risk breaking anything on their production environments. Things like this is why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but try this out:

1. Windows -> preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> compiler compliance -> 1.5
2. Windows -> preferences -> Java -> Installed JRE -> set up an 1.5 (download and install one, if there is only 1.6)

Comment: Thanks  After changing the JRE to 1.5, everything worked.  I thought only the compiler should be only setting used when building.

Comment: Your welcome. If my answer was helpful, please mark it accordingly. Thanks ;-)